# Problem assigning probabilities in sample function

Tags: r

I have generated a bunch of variables through the following :

```
max_no=10
list2env(setNames(as.list(c(0.2, 0.25,0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03, 0.06, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01)), paste0("proportion", 0:max_no)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

These generate objects like "proportion0", "proportion1",..., "proportion10" with values 0.2, 0.25.... etc.

I want to plug these proportion values as a vector of probabilities into the sample function like the following:

```
sample(seq.int(0, max_no, 1), size=10000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(paste0("proportion", 0:max_no)))
```

But I get the error message: Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : NA in probability vector

What would be a simple way of feeding in the probabilities?

Comment: Why are you putting all these proportions into different variables? That makes it very hard to work with. Why not just keep them in a simple vector that you can pass to `prob=`? Just `probs <- c(0.2, 0.25,0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03, 0.06, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01)` and `sample(seq.int(0, max_no, 1), size=10000, replace=TRUE, prob=probs)`. You can get at individual values with `probs[1]`, `probs[2]`, etc

Comment: I'm running a simulation which would require dynamic creation of variables. The option I went with looked easiest in terms of creating and changing probabilities..

Comment: I would strongly recommend against it. It's going to be much easier to do things with `proportion[1]`, `proportion[2]`, etc rather than `proportion0`, `proportion1`, etc. Variables with indexes in their name is a sign that you aren't doing things in a very "R-like" way which is just making things harder on yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is the use-case for this but you can use `mget` and `unlist`

```
sample(seq.int(0, max_no, 1), size=10000, replace=TRUE, 
       prob=unlist(mget(c(paste0("proportion", 0:max_no)))))
```

Why not pass probability directly instead of storing each number in a different variable?

```
sample(seq.int(0, max_no, 1), size=10000, replace=TRUE, 
       prob=c(0.2, 0.25,0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03, 0.06, 0.03, 0.02, 0.01))
```